# Timeouts not supported on this Stream

Tags: .net, .net-core

I used have an API that used to connect to a mailing service that sends mail. One of the parameters that was provided by this mailing service was a Stream for Attachments. The sendMail function was synchronous so I did not have any problem

Except that we are trying to make a new API similar to the one above. While the original is regular .NET, The new one we are using uses .NET Core 2,0. Which means that connecting to that service, everything becomes asynchronous.

I wanted to make my service run like this

```
        try
        {
            // Send the email.
            var result = mailService.SendMailWithMessageAsync(emailMessage, "DefaultMail").Result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string error = ex.ToString();
        }
```

And I got the memory timeout not supported. If I do not use any attachments, my mail service will work fine.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why the `'Result' ? IS the caller not async?

Comment: I was trying to imitate the behavior of the original API which isn't async.

Comment: Also .NET Core wraps all connected services to make them asynchronous. So if you attach a service called mail and has a function called SendMail,, The mail service you have now has a function called SendMailAsync instead of the original SendMail that is in your mail service.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that this is a .NET Core 2.0 Problem, I created the same console program using .NET Framework 4.6.1 and I had no problem with this one. The Mail Service I connected is being developed by a different group and I found out now that I am having trouble when I use .NET Core 2.0 instead of .NET Standard 4.6.1

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ConnectedMailService;

namespace MailSender
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                MainAsync(args).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                Console.WriteLine("Email Send End!");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.ToString());
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static async Task MainAsync(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Email Send Start!");

            MailServiceClient mailService = new ConnectedMailService.MailServiceClient();

            EMailMessage emailMessage = new EMailMessage();
            emailMessage.Subject = "Email Subject Test";
            emailMessage.To = new EmailRecipient[1];
            emailMessage.To[0] = new EmailRecipient();
            emailMessage.To[0].recipientEmail = "nino@mail.com";
            emailMessage.From = "test@mail.com";
            emailMessage.Body = "Email Body Test.";

            StreamAttachment streamAttachment = new StreamAttachment();
            streamAttachment.attachment = new MemoryStream(new byte[] { 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35 });
            streamAttachment.fileName = "12345.txt";
            emailMessage.streamAttachments = new StreamAttachment[1];
            emailMessage.streamAttachments[0] = streamAttachment;

            var retVal = await mailService.SendMailWithMessageAsync(emailMessage, "DefaultMail");
        }
    }
}
```

Have you guys encountered something like this?